# Form property automatically changing on saving changes in VB6 (configured with VSS 2005)

Tags: vb6, visual-sourcesafe

I am facing below issue in VB6 :

When I checkout file file and check "Show differences" it is showing no difference (identical files) but when I save my changes without changing and form property and again check for differences in VSS , it is showing difference in few property.One of them is mentioned below.Kindly suggest.

```
Begin VB.Label CommStatus 
      BackColor       =   &H80000014&
      BorderStyle     =   1  'Fixed Single
      BeginProperty Font 
         **Name            =   "Arial"**   'this property is changing
         Size            =   8.25
         Charset         =   204
         Weight          =   700
         Underline       =   0   'False
         Italic          =   0   'False
         Strikethrough   =   0   'False
      EndProperty
      ForeColor       =   &H000000C0&
      Height          =   375
      Left            =   240
      TabIndex        =   3
      ToolTipText     =   "The most recently detected error"
      Top             =   360
      Width           =   7815
   End
```

You can check attach image[image: Showing property difference in VSS]

Comment: VB6 is changing the font for some reason. Do you have the MS Sans Serif font available on your computer?

Comment: It would be a weird machine that didn't have MS Sans Serif

Comment: Yes MS Sans Serif font available on my machine.Other than Font name there are other format also changing.

Comment: Any solutions for this one? I experience the exact same thing...

Answer (score 0):

After looking in to this, the reason for seems to be Windows zoom setting (100%,125% and 150%, control panel/Make text and other items larger or smaller). If the form is checked in to TFS/VSS/GIT in one zoom setting, and later edited in another, VB6 will change all kind of form properties to adjust for this. So this probably only happens in dev teams with 2+ users that happens to have different screen sizes and therefor different zoom settings.

Only way to avoid this is probably to all use the same zoom setting...